# AVAssetExporter and UIImagePickerViewController Video

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetexportsession

Im building an iOS video application that uses AVFoundation to Capture Video.
When starting the app I create a AVCaptureSession, when the user presses on the Record button, video is captured and written to a Documents folder under a "temp.MOV" name.
This is no problem for my AVAssetExporter, which merges and reformats my composition.

But, if I try and use Video from the UIImagePicker, the AVAssetExporter stops with error.

```
Export failed: Operation Stopped
Export failed: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11841 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo=0x17db5100 {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The video could not be composed.}
```

Im wondering if there is something special that needs to be done with video from the UIImagePicker.

//File Written from the AVCaptureSession

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error{

NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL %@", outputFileURL); 
//DOCUMENTS/temp.mov
self.movieFileURLForExport = outputFileURL; 

}
```

Code for UIImagePickerController Video Import

```
- (IBAction)iba_importVideo:(id)sender{

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc]
                     initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
NSString *type = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo] ||
    [type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {


    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSLog(@"PickedVideoURL %@", [videoURL absoluteString]);

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

    NSString *dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/films"];
    NSString *moviepath = [dataPath stringByAppendingString:@"/temp.mov"];

    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:moviepath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"Write Successs: %@", success ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    [self checkDIRECTORYContents];
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

   self.movieFileURLForExport = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviepath]; 

    [picker  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.
Previously when I was creating my AVAssetExporter I was using

```
AVAssetURL
```

To load my NSURL for the picked video.

I changed it to

```
 AVAsset *videoasset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:videoURL];
```

and that fixed the issue.

Im not sure why this corrected the UIImagePicker Picked Videos, and not videos shot through AVfoundation and saved to a location. But Corrected my issue.